# Why is UserDefaults.init(suiteName:) a failable initializer?

Tags: swift, userdefaults

The [UserDefaults.init(suiteName:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/userdefaults/1409957-init) initializer is a failable initializer. However, the documentation does not specify the circumstances under which it will return a nil [UserDefaults](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/userdefaults) object.

Firstly, what are the circumstances under which it will return a nil [UserDefaults](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/userdefaults) object?

Secondly, am I safe to force-unwrap it in the context of an iPhone and iPad application?

Comment: Use `UserDefaults.globalDomain` for the `suiteName` and it seems to return nil value. In the doc, it's states that's an invalid param, as the bundle id, I guess that passing the bundle id might fail also.

Comment: Perfect. I missed that in the `suiteName` parameter description. Now that I re-read it, it makes sense. So if I pass in a value which is not my app's main bundle identifier nor [globalDomain](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/userdefaults/1407355-globaldomain), I guess I'm okay to assume that I'll get out a non-nil `UserDefaults` object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [UserDefaults.init(suiteName:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/userdefaults/1409957-init) initializer will return a nil [UserDefaults](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/userdefaults) object if it is passed the app's main bundle identifier or [globalDomain](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/userdefaults/1407355-globaldomain). If you're passing in any other value, it is my guess that you're okay to assume that this initializer will return a non-nil [UserDefaults](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/userdefaults) object.

(Thank you to [@Larme](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1801544/larme) for his/her comment under my question.)

Comment: So I assume it is safe to write `let current = UserDefaults.init(suiteName: XXX)!` with force cast which XXX is an user identifier ?

Comment: Yes, the force unwrap is fine as long as `XXX` is not your app's main bundle identifier or [globalDomain](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/userdefaults/1407355-globaldomain).